# Email a notification when detecting changes on a website - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, web-scraping

I read through other questions here and improved the code and added a new feature. The old question can be found at: [Email a notification when detecting changes on a website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119951/email-a-notification-when-detecting-changes-on-a-website)

The improvements that are done until now:

- Using a difflib.SequenceMatcher
- Added a logger
- Using format for strings
- Exceptions are now logged and then reraised
- The code should now follow the suggestions in PEP8 (checked with [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8))
- Added a config file
- Docstrings
- New variable and function names

My questions are:

- Is there still something wrong with the improvements?
- Sometimes the code get stuck when finding the differences in big sites like http://www.welt.de. How could that be avoided?
- Is there anything that could be done differently?
- Are there any features missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import configparser
import datetime
import difflib
import hashlib
import html2text
import logging
import smtplib
import time
import urllib.request


class UrlChange:
    """ URL is checked and a hash is made. Changes are regcognized and
    reported
    """

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.url_hash = self.create_hash()
        self.content = self.get_content()
        logger.info(("Start Monitoring... hash "
                    "{url_hash}").format(url_hash=self.url_hash))

    def get_content(self):
        """ The data is read from the url. """
        try:
            url_data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
            url_data = url_data.read()
            url_data = url_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
            url_data = html2text.html2text(url_data)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical("Error: {}".format(e))
            raise
        return url_data

    def create_hash(self):
        """ A md5 hash is created from the url_data. """
        url_data = self.get_content().encode("utf-8")
        md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
        md5_hash.update(url_data)
        return md5_hash.hexdigest()

    def compare_hash(self):
        """ The hash is compared with the stored value. If there is a change
        a function is opend witch alerts the user.
        """
        if(self.create_hash() == self.url_hash):
            logger.info("Nothing has changed")
            return False
        else:
            logger.info("Something has changed")
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
            if(not args.nomail):
                send_mail("Url has changed!",
                        ("The Url {url} has changed at "
                        "{date} .").format(url=self.url, date=date))
            if(not args.nodiff):
                diff = self.diff()
                logger.info("{diff}".format(**locals()))
                if(not args.nomail):
                    diff.encode("ascii", "ignore")
                    send_mail("Url difference!",
                            ("The Url {url} has changed at {date} ."
                            "\n\nNew content\n{diff}").format(url=self.url,
                                                                date=date,
                                                                diff=diff))
            return True

    def diff(self):
        """ The function tries to extract the changed part of the url content.
        """
        result = ""
        new_content = self.get_content()
        s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, self.content, new_content)
        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
            if(tag == "insert" or tag == "replaced"):
                result += new_content[j1:j2]
        return result


def send_mail(subject, message):
    """ A connection to the smtp server is build. A mail is sent. """
    try:
        smtp_url = config["SMTP"]["url"]
        smtp_port = config["SMTP"]["port"]
        smtp_user = config["SMTP"]["user"]
        smtp_password = config["SMTP"]["password"]
        destination = config["SMTP"]["destination"]

        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_url, smtp_port)
        server.set_debuglevel(0)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)
    except Exception as e:
            logger.critical("Error: {}".format(e))
            raise

    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    msg = ("From: {source}\nSubject: {subject}\nDate: {date}\n"
        "\n{message}").format(source=smtp_user, subject=subject, date=date,
                                message=message)

    server.sendmail(smtp_user, destination, msg)
    server.quit()
    logging.info("email was sent")

# Arguments from the console are parsed
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                                description=("Monitor ifa website"
                                            "has changed.")
                                )
parser.add_argument("url", help="url that should be monitored")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time",
                    help="seconds between checks (default: 600)",
                    default=600, type=int)
parser.add_argument("-nd", "--nodiff", help="show no difference",
                    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--nomail", help="no email is sent",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

# A new logging object is created
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
                    datefmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Parse the configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
try:
    config.read("config.conf")
    if("SMTP" not in config):
        raise ValueError("Can't find smtp data in config.conf")
except Exception as e:
    logger.critical("Error: {}".format(e))
    raise

# Main part
url1 = UrlChange(args.url)
time.sleep(args.time)
while(True):
    if(url1.compare_hash()):
        break
    time.sleep(args.time)
```

Comment: How do you expect us to comment upon what features you are missing in your program? What is your goal programming this, what is it that you are aiming for? What do you want to use it for? These are questions for you to answer, not us.

Comment: Okay, perhaps features is the false word at this point. I mean things like: "it is bad practice to read a url from the command line and try to reach it without any parsing/checking. so there should be a _feature_ which checks the url"

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your script! I have tested and it works great. But in mine case I also need a email notification when someone add's a hyperlink(url) into the text. Now I only get a notification when there actually change text on the specific page.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I could add this feature in the script?
When I look at the module HTML2Text, you have a option to make links visible.
Example: ignore_links = False but when I try to add this in the script I will get a invaild paramater or something. Could someone please help?